# Live drawing on tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I need to draw many lines/polygons on a canvas but i want to display the canvas first and then see every object while is drawn.

Here is my code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width=800)
canvas.pack()

draw_something(canvas)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that python shows the canvas after drawing everything and this is not what i want.

Comment: Try `root.after(1000, draw_something, canvas)` Instead of calling `draw_something` directly before mainloop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following example, 10 random lines will be created every second on the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def make_segment():
    return [random.randrange(0, 800) for _ in range(4)]

def draw_random_lines():
    canvas.create_line(*make_segment())
    root.after(100, draw_random_lines)

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=800, width=800)
canvas.pack()

draw_random_lines()

root.mainloop()
```